# Redirect https://www.subdomain.example.com to https://subdomain.example.com (drop www)

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx conf:

```
ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/collabora.example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/collabora.example.com/privkey.pem;

server {
    
    listen          80;
    server_name     www.collabora.example.com;
    server_name     collabora.example.com;
    
    return 301 https://collabora.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     www.collabora.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://collabora.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     collabora.example.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://collabora:9980;
        access_log off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

With this set up the following redirects function as desired:

```
www.collabora.example.com redirects to https://collabora.example.com
collabora.example.com redirects to https://collabora.example.com
```

However, this redirect does not occur, ssl www to non www:

```
https://www.collabora.example.com  : no redirect, instead site cert warning.
```

How can I adjust my blocks so that `https://www.collabora.example.com` redirects to `https://collabora.example.com`?

Comment: You should use `listen 443 ssl;` and include the certificate files for the `www` domain.

Comment: @RichardSmith see my edit. I included paths to the cert files at the top (which I had already but just left of the post while trying to be minimal). I also changed the listen on the second block from `listen          443;` to `listen          443 ssl;` but I get the same behavior after this change. You said "include the certificate files for the `www` domain". I don't think I have those, just for the non www version when I got the cert from letsencrypt. I thought I could just redirect to non www no?

Comment: What's the norm I guess?

Comment: Any site warning is coming from the browser and not Nginx. If the certificate is not valid for the www domain, the browser will generate a warning. Often certificate are created to be valid for both the www and non-www domains. Clearly this certificate is not.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith. I checked on another browser and actually it seems to be working fine there! It's just on my main browser ff that this is happening :/   I wonder if there's a timelag or permanent chaching thing in my browser going on

Comment: In the first `server` block you have two `server_name` directives. I'm not sure that's valid. You should use: `server_name www.collabora.example.com collabora.example.com;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing that now. The behavior is unchanged

Answer (score 1):

Lets encrypt lets you create certificates which are valid for more than one URL.
You could try to create a certificate (or update yours) with the www. and normal version of your website.

This answer is based on the questions asked by @richardSmith.